# Node.JS, node-imagemagick: Invalid paramaters/ENOENT on function call

Tags: node.js

I am writing Node.js script to create thumbnails with imagemagick. I running Windows 10. I have installed the latest Windows Binary release of ImageMagick, selecting the options to add it to the path and install legacy utilities (e.g., convert). I am using `node-imagemagick` to interface with ImageMagick from my script.

I can successfully use ImageMagick from the command line. For example, if I run the following command `convert C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/in.jpg -resize 150x150 C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/out.jpg` ImageMagick will create a thumbnail. However, if I run the convert function with the same arguments in my  Node.js script:

```
var im = require('imagemagick');

im.convert(['C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/in.jpg', '-resize', '150x150', 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/out.jpg'], function (err, stdout) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('stdout:', stdout);
});
```

Returns an error

```
Error: Command failed: Invalid Parameter - /Users

at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Projects\node_script\node_modules\imagemagick\imagemagick.js:88:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5) {
  timedOut: false,
  killed: false,
  code: 4,
  signal: null
}
```

In case this was because of the path separators being different on Windows, I tried replacing the slashes with double backslashes and surrounding the paths in quotes `['"C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\in.jpg"',...`. However, I instead get the error `Error: Command failed: Invalid Parameter - -resize`.

This also happens with the identify command. `identify -format %[EXIF:*] C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/in.jpg` sucussfully returns information about my image while my Node.js script:

```
im.identify(['identify', 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/in.jpg'], function(err, features){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(features);
});
```

Returns an error

```
Error: spawn identify ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn identify',
  path: 'identify',
  spawnargs: [ 'identify', 'C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/in.jpg' ]
}
```

If these errors are not correctable or are unnecessarily hard to correct, is there a better way to create thumbnails in Node.js? I will eventually need to be able to generate thumbnails for videos and .swf files. The last publish of `node-imagemagick` was 7 years ago, is there anything more recent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a comment saying to restart your device if using node imagemagick with Windows. After a restart commands called from the Node.js script worked without errors.

Answer (score 2):

There is a much better alternative and actively maintained solution to `node-imagemagick` called [sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/).

**Usage (based on your question):**

```
const sharp = require('sharp');

sharp('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/in.jpg')
    .resize(150, 150)
    .toFile('C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/out.jpg')
    .then(outputInfo => {
        console.log(outputInfo);
    })
    .catch(reason => {
        console.log(reason);
    });
```